# Позиционирование/обтекание элементов div

Tags: html, css

Хочу наложить один блок div на другой. При этом нужно его правильно позиционировать. Я пытался делать через `position:absolute`, но это не годится, т.к. блок становиться не адаптивным. Хочу чтобы блок `signform` был над блоком `bg` и при этом позиционировался относительно блока `bg`.

```css
.bg {
  background-color: rgba(15, 26, 47, 0.9);
  max-width: 920px;
  height: 420px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 105px;
  z-index: 36;
}

.signform {
  background-color: rgb( 255, 255, 255);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 140px 0px rgb( 50, 66, 91);
  width: 462px;
  height: 462px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="bg">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-offset-3  goodsleft">
          <h3>Don't have an account?</h3>
          <hr class="hidden-xs">
          <p class="hidden-xs">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere dolorem totam, ipsum dolore asperiores nihil alias id modi tempore, laudantium soluta dicta, vel enim possimus vero, autem libero. Reiciendis, quasi?</p>
          <button type="button" class="login">Sign Up</button>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-3 col-xs-offset-3 goodsright">
          <h3>Have an account?</h3>
          <hr class="hidden-xs">
          <p class="hidden-xs">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet <br> consectetur adipisicing elit?</p>
          <button type="button" class="login">Login</button>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="signform ">
        <div class="signcont">
          <h3>Login</h3>
          <img src="img/logo.png" alt="">
          <br>
          <hr>
          <br>
          <p>Email<span>*</span></p>
          <img src="img/ic_mail.png" alt="">
          <input type="text" class="datainput">
          <p>Password<span>*</span></p>
          <img src="img/ic_lock.png" alt="">
          <input type="password" class="datainput">
          <button type="submit" class="inputsubmit">Login</button>
          <a href="#">Forgot?</a>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос полноценную разметку и текущие стили. [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы блок `.signform` позиционировался относительно `.bg` надо его разместить внутри `.bg` . А потом можно просто не задавая размеры блоку .signform сделать его резиновым с помощью задания координат. Например:

```css
.bg {
  background-color: rgba(15, 26, 47, 0.9);
  max-width: 920px;
  height: 420px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 105px;
  z-index: 36;
  position: relative;
}

.signform {
  background-color: rgb( 255, 255, 255);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 140px 0px rgb( 50, 66, 91);
  max-width: 462px;
  max-height: 462px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="bg">
<div class="signform ">
        <div class="signcont">
          <h3>Login</h3>
          <img src="img/logo.png" alt="">
          <br>
          <hr>
          <br>
          <p>Email<span>*</span></p>
          <img src="img/ic_mail.png" alt="">
          <input type="text" class="datainput">
          <p>Password<span>*</span></p>
          <img src="img/ic_lock.png" alt="">
          <input type="password" class="datainput">
          <button type="submit" class="inputsubmit">Login</button>
          <a href="#">Forgot?</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-offset-3  goodsleft">
          <h3>Don't have an account?</h3>
          <hr class="hidden-xs">
          <p class="hidden-xs">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere dolorem totam, ipsum dolore asperiores nihil alias id modi tempore, laudantium soluta dicta, vel enim possimus vero, autem libero. Reiciendis, quasi?</p>
          <button type="button" class="login">Sign Up</button>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-3 col-xs-offset-3 goodsright">
          <h3>Have an account?</h3>
          <hr class="hidden-xs">
          <p class="hidden-xs">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet <br> consectetur adipisicing elit?</p>
          <button type="button" class="login">Login</button>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Чел, красавчик, спасибо